# Editing Many RichTextBoxes and TextBoxes

Tags: .net, forms, richtextbox, editing

How do i cut,copy,paste from main menu in a multi textboxes form ?

How does the menu knows to apply on the active textbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this article here on [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/TcMagicalEditMenu.aspx) that does the job in synchronizing each text box's "standard" edit menu such as Copy, Cut, Paste, Undo, Select All. Of course, the code originally targets the .NET 1.1, but it can be easily recompiled to target the newer frameworks as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the menu click event you can examine `this.ActiveControl` to see what control currently has input focus.