# windows form applications' cut copy paste functionality

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have windows forms application with multiple forms and controls in them. I want if user has selected some text in any control of any form of my application and click on cut/copy/paste button on toolbar operation get performed accordingly.

i m using C#.net's sendkeys.send("^c") on click of copy button but it doesn't work...

OR any 1 can tell if is there any way to get selected text (despite of knowing, which form/control of my application).

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Unhelpful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881259/editing-many-richtextboxes-and-textboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this in the method handling the copy event:

```
if (this.ActiveControl is TextBox)
{
      Clipboard.SetDataObject(((TextBox)this.ActiveControl).SelectedText, true);
}
if (this.ActiveControl is RichTextBox)
{
      Clipboard.SetDataObject(((RichTextBox)this.ActiveControl).SelectedText, true);
}
if (this.ActiveControl is ComboBox)
{
       Clipboard.SetDataObject(((ComboBox)this.ActiveControl).SelectedText, true);
}
```

For paste, something like this:

```
nCursorPosition = ((RichTextBox)this.ActiveControl).SelectionStart;
this.ActiveControl.Text = this.ActiveControl.Text.Insert(nCursorPosition, Clipboard.GetText());
```

Comment: i have mdi application with multiple forms 
each form can have multiple textboxes
when user select some text in any form
and press copy button in main menu of the application
i want that selected text get copied

Answer (score 5):

have you used clipboard to copy and paste you data if not than use clipboard for this

check this article for more about  clipboard: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial188_Clipboard-Copy-and-Paste-with-Csharp.html

Comment: Thanks for  your reply. I checked the link. in that case programmer knows which textbox is selected. i want generic solution. suppose i have data grid with thousands of rows and columns. now i don't know which cells text user selected. i have many forms to deal with. as user can open multiple forms at the same time. so i dont wanna implement such technique for each control and form. just looking for generic way.

Comment: than check this may help you : http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/winforms/part8.shtml

Answer (score 1):

To your second question:

You can use this solution [What is the preferred way to find focused control in WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435433/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-find-focused-control-in-winforms-app/439606#439606) to find the currently focused control.

Then check, what type it is to read the selection (i.e. if it is `TextBox` use `SelectedText`-Propery http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectedtext.aspx)

Comment: it doesn't work for me. as i have MDI application. by getting active control i get clicked button of toolbar rather that textbox where i selected text of another form (mdi child)